# Background service that checkes change in a file

Tags: sharepoint-2007, windows-services, powerpoint, sharepoint-api

I haven't done any coding of this kind and would like some pointers how to start. The service will eventually do several things and perhaps someone has already thought of it made it happen.

The big picture is this: Detect if a PowerPoint presentation has been updated on the server. If it has extract the slides and save them as individual jpegs then upload them to a specific image list in SharePoint. All this has to happen without human intervention.

I assume this would be a window service project, right? Then a file stream property that with some property that deals with changes in the file?

As far as dissecting a .pptx/.ppsx files and get the slides converted, it there a "api" or some dll class?

What about uploading files to a library list on SharePoint automatically?

Thanks,

Risho

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in Topshelf http://topshelf-project.com/, a windows service host for .NET.

https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/blob/master/src/Topshelf/FileSystem/FileSystemEventProducer.cs

Since Windows has an event pump issue if events take too long, we also implemented polling on top of this since the `FileSystemWatcher` gets disconnected during those times.

https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/blob/master/src/Topshelf/FileSystem/PollingFileSystemEventProducer.cs

Now, these producers are supposed to be tied to actors so they might seem a bit overly complicated for just checking on file system events. It's up to use if that model is useful or just the core part. Remember that you can often receive events even if the file is locked or not done yet, so handle those exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has what is called a timer service for just these types of situations. Andrew Connell has an article regarding creating your own timer jobs.

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2007/01/10/5704.aspx